Power BI Relationship between two tables
Please if anyone can help me to make relationship between two tables as shown in the attached pictures.
It always tells me it's a many to many relationship, but I need it to be Many to one.



Most likely it means that keys in the table you want on the "1" side are not unique. Examine your data for duplicates, including blanks.
